# Force Python function to return type 'tuple'

Tags: python, django, tuples

I've run into an interesting problem I can't seem to solve.  I have a pretty complicated system that calls a formatting tool, which is defined as a class for each format we support.  The class name is determined dynamically and the value is formatted based on our client's documentation for an API POST.

The problem I've run into is that some values require a single key/value pair `(key, value)` whereas some require multiple pairs, which I put into a list of tuples `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2)]`.

What I need to do is get the key(s)/value(s) and create a tuple of tuples and pass it along for delivery.  I cannot use a dictionary as order may be of significance later.

The overall structure of this code is quite vast so I'll try to break it down into small pieces for readability.

calling_function:

```
def map_lead(self, lead):
    mapto_data = tuple()
    for offer_field in self.offerfield_set.all():
        field_name = offer_field.field.name
        if field_name not in lead.data:
            raise LeadMissingField(lead, field_name)

        formatted_list = format_value(offer_field.mapto, lead.data[field_name])

        if type(formatted_list).__name__ == 'list':
            for item in formatted_list:
                mapto_data += (item,)

        elif type(formatted_list).__name__ == 'tuple':
            mapto_data += (formatted_list)
        return mapto_data
```

example_format_type1:

```
@staticmethod
def do_format(key, value):
    area_code, exchange, number = PhoneFormat.format_phone(value)
        return [
            (PhoneFormat.AREA_CODE_MAPTO, area_code),
            (PhoneFormat.PHONE_EXCHANGE_MAPTO, exchange),
            (PhoneFormat.VANTAGE_MEDIA_HOME_PHONE_NUMBER_MAPTO, number)
        ]
```

example_format_type2:

```
@staticmethod
def do_format(key, value):
    if len(value) > 3:
        value = value[:3] + '-' + value[3:]
        if len(value) > 7:
            value = value[:7] + '-' + value[7:]
    return key, value
```

I've tried to explicitly define the return value of the `example_format_type2` to be a tuple:

```
@staticmethod
def do_format(key, value):
    if len(value) > 3:
        value = value[:3] + '-' + value[3:]
        if len(value) > 7:
            value = value[:7] + '-' + value[7:]
    formatted_value = tuple()
    formatted_value += (key, value)
    return formatted_value
```

But it seems that regardless of what I do it gets interpreted as a list in `calling_function`.

So, I always get `type(formatted_list).__name__ == 'list'`.  So, if it is a tuple I'm returning the `for` loop goes through each item in the tuple and adds it as a single value in the `mapto_data` tuple.

Is there a way to force Python to return the value from `example_format_type2` such that it will be interpreted in `calling_function` as a tuple?

EDIT1:

It turns out the problem was in `map_lead` where I was adding to the `mapto_data` tuple.  I missed the trailing comma there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting you. What you call "calling_function" (it's `map_lead`, right) does not even try to speculate on type of it's parameters. Are you sure returning `tuple` is what you want to achieve? What's the real purpose of the code?

Comment: a side note: you should replace `type(formatted_list).__name__ == 'list'` with `isinstance(formatted_list, list)`.  And the same for the tuple

Comment: I don't think I've understood what you're doing - it almost appears you want some kind of dispatch system (but possibly using classes for that), but instead it doesn't appear to be so, but then at the same time you're trying to make it appear to be!? Just give us a leading paragraph in English what you're trying to do without any technical details involved... (this should start with "What I'd like to achieve is..."

Comment: `formatted_list = format_value(offer_field.mapto, lead.data[field_name])`  what is `format_value`?

Comment: `return key, value` definitely returns a tuple.  Are you sure you're calling that method?

Comment: `Is there a way to force Python to return the value from example_format_type2 such that it will be interpreted in calling_function as a tuple?`  - yes - there is, but I don't think that's your actual question - it'd help everyone (including yourself) if you just said what you're trying to achieve in paragraph and maybe a few bullet points

Comment: You know about [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), right? And [`MultiDict`](https://webob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#module-webob.multidict)? These are both dictionaries that preserve order. `MultiDict` even allows multiple values per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just return a tuple literal (idk if that is what it is called)?

```
>>> def test():
...     return (1, 2)
... 
>>> thing = test()
>>> thing
(1, 2)
>>> type(thing)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(thing).__name__
'tuple'
```

Answer (score 0):

`example_format_type2` does return a tuple, I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere else. Like in the `format_value` function. Note that if you add a tuple to a list with += the result will be a list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a += (3, 4)
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Also consider checking the type of `formatted_list` using this syntax:

```
if type(formatted_list) is tuple:
  ...
```